# $P(a \leq X \leq b) = 0.95$ to find z scores $a$ and $b$

Tags: probability

I have this question to solve, find $a$ with $b$ and that $a \neq -b$ such that $P(a \leq X \leq b) = 0.95$ knowing that $X \sim N(0, 1)$

This is my try:

If we had $ a = -b$ then this property would hold $P(X \leq a) + P(X \leq b) = 1$

But since we don't have $ a = -b$ then $P(a \leq X \leq b) = P(X \leq b) - P(X \leq a) = 0.95$ How to go about getting the z-scores $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: I might be confused, but wouldn't there be infinitely many such pairs $a$ and $b$?

Comment: You're right, but just one methodic way to find any $a$ and $b$?